# How to center an image using blogdown?

Tags: html, markdown, hugo, blogdown

So I am building my first data blog with RStudio and Blogdown and I am seriously stuck on something small but infuriating.

https://data-issues.netlify.app/

Above is the site I am building. I made a logo for it but I would like to make this centered. How would I do so in my markdown (.md) file.

Code here:

```
---
# Homepage
type: widget_page

# Homepage is headless, other widget pages are not.
headless: true

weight: 1

design:
  columns: "1"
---

{{< figure src=/datavision.png theme="light" class="center">}}
```

EDIT: added this too to no avail

```
<p align="center">
![datavision](datavision.png)
</p>
```

I am using .md files, so where exactly would I define the shortcode for p if not here?

Comment: I have two questions, first question, are you using Hugo ? I don't think you're using it but you put the tag.  Second question, is the CSS class named as **center** correct ? I opened your website and I did a check with the developer console on the image but I don't see that the class is used. You can check this [issue](https://community.rstudio.com/t/centering-images-in-blogdown-post/20962) on the RStudio community if it is helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @MalwareWerewolf, yup blogdown depends on Hugo for the build. I know little to no css, I just googled how to center, and i added that parameter but it looks like its doing nothing

Comment: @MalwareWerewolf I added this too from the post you shared , but to no avail <p align="center">
![datavision](datavision.png) . Error : failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "p" not found
</p>

Comment: Two solutions (I don't have time to post a formal answer): 1. If you use raw HTML, you have to use full HTML because Hugo doesn't support mixing up Markdown and HTML (change `![]()` to `<img .../>`); 2. If you like my idea of centering images, you may add `center-img.js` to your Hugo template: https://github.com/yihui/misc.js That way, images will be automatically centered.

Comment: I like the latter idea @YihuiXie; but where in the project do I put this file for it to work appropriately?

Comment: One possible place is here: https://github.com/johnnytommy/data-issues-blog/blob/main/layouts/partials/custom_js.html

Comment: @YihuiXie ; this worked!!! Would you also be able to quickly give your two cents on what’s going wrong here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637655/hugo-params-in-blogdown-site-logo-and-custom-fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@YihuiXie** said in the comment section below, you don't really need to use a shortcode for raw HTML, there are multiple solutions that you can use.

---

### Edit your config to use raw HTML in Markdown

In your `config.toml` enter:

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

If you have in your project `config.yaml` use this:

```
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

This enables raw html support in markdown files, in this way you don't need to use shortcodes.

https://gohugo.io/news/0.60.0-relnotes/

---

### Raw HTML using Shortcodes

Depending how your project is structured, there should be some kind of `layouts` folder. I have a project made with **Hugo** and I have a something like this `../layouts/shortcodes/rawhtml.html` with this code:

```
{{.Inner}}
```

For example in your code you're already using a [Hugo’s Built-in shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#use-hugos-built-in-shortcodes). After you create the file, you just need to insert your shortcode in this way in your Markdown:

```
{{< rawhtml >}}
  <img src=/datavision.png class="center">
{{< /rawhtml >}}
```

The **custom CSS code** should be defined in `../static/css/`, in your `config.toml`, simply check if there is a variable to set your custom CSS code, for example:

```
# Custom CSS
customCSS = ["/css/custom.css"]
```

I used this configuration because the theme required it, but it can be different in your project so keep this in mind. If you don't want to use another file to save your CSS code, you can simply insert it into your shortcode like I did with the HTML, for example:

```
{{< rawhtml >}}
<style>
    .center{
        /* your code here */
    }
</style>

{{< /rawhtml >}}
```

---

### Use HTML for content pages instead of Markdown

With Hugo, you could also use a HTML instead of a md file in your project. It simply follows the same syntax, but you have to use HTML instead of the Markdown syntax, for example:

```
---
title: "Contact me"
---

<p>
    Some text here
</p>
```

In this case you don't need the shortcode from the moment you're already using a HTML.

Comment: You don't really need a shortcode for raw HTML. Hugo's Markdown renderer supports raw HTML, although this feature is turned off by default (see https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/447#issuecomment-613196974).

Comment: I read something about that on the documentation but I never used that feature, thanks for the info another good feature to use.