# Custom fonts not updating in params in Hugo via Blogdown

Tags: html, markdown, hugo, blogdown, toml

So I have been learning Blogdown to build my personal data blog: https://data-issues.netlify.app/

Built with the academic theme, I did change the colors with no issue.

I am making some changes in my `params.yaml` file but no changes I make here are happening. I but it seems like its identical to everything I've seen online.

So here is an excerpt from my [params.yaml](https://github.com/johnnytommy/data-issues-blog/blob/main/config/_default/params.yaml) file.

```
theme: "datavision"
day_night: true
font: datavision_fonts
font_size: L
```

I set new fonts in a file called [datavision_fonts.toml](https://github.com/johnnytommy/data-issues-blog/blob/main/data/fonts/datavision_fonts.toml)

**datavision_fonts.toml**

```
# Font style metadata
name = "datavision_fonts"

# Optional Google font URL
google_fonts = "family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto:wght@400;700;family=Lato:wght@900;Lato"

# Font families
heading_font = "Lato"
body_font = "Lato"
nav_font = "Lato"
mono_font = "Lato"
```

The goal here is to have the fonts be all `Lato` in this example but once it is fixed I want the liberty of choosing any google font I please.

Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/johnnytommy/data-issues-blog

Comment: Mate, a few question: What theme are you using? Why would you define your logo and fonts in params, is that solving some other problem? Do you have a template/partial/shortcode that's calling the variable from your config? Did you build your own theme, if you did, did you find why the site variables is question are not being called?

Comment: @Rogelio using Academic theme. I did build my own theme yes, but that works perfectly fine. I have since fixed the issue with the logo so that is no longer a problem but i still cannot figure out fonts. I was instructed in the wowchemy site that this is where fonts is supposed to be set.

Comment: @Rogelio I did link my github repo above if that helps, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not connecting to my fonts file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the URL that you are using.

Can you try replacing the `google_fonts` parameter in `datavision_fonts.toml` with the following ?

```
"family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Lato:wght@900&display=swap"
```

Here is [link to my deployment](https://confident-montalcini-f40b72.netlify.app/) with this fix, showing up Lato correctly.

Comment: will award bounty when able!